# Make MERGE Data in Target Table visible as View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Very new to SQL Server 2008, so I appreciate your patience and help.
I have data in two tables that I need to merge and allow users to see the combined data in the updated target table. Users access this data by ODBC links to Views in SQL - I cannot figure out how to keep the merged data in the target table up to date and make a View of the merged data in the updated target table visible to users. MERGE code below works perfectly when I execute it but when I add

`CREATE VIEW vwNewView AS`

I get

`'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'MERGE'`

How do I solve this?
Thanks

```
MERGE [DSSQL01\Manufacturing].[FieldFeedback].[dbo].[Process Changes] AS P
USING
(
  SELECT [Current Job]
  FROM [DSSQL01\Manufacturing].[Manufacturing].[dbo].[LaserMarkingOutput]
  GROUP BY [Current Job]
) As L
ON P.[Lot Number]=L.[Current Job]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT([Lot Number],[Laser Rev 0])
VALUES(L.[Current Job],'Laser Rev 5');
```

Comment: Can you be more precise where you want to add the view? Please correct the question too. Thanks.

Comment: Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx only `select_statement` is supported. `MERGE` is actually making changes to table.

Comment: @Denn What's wrong with the question that needs corrected? The view needs to be in the same database as the target table.